# Why doesn't Picasso display full images?

Tags: android

I have an `android` app that uses `Picasso` to load images. Problem is that it doesn't load the `image` the first time. It just gives me an empty `fragment`. It loads it fine after I return back to my thumbnail `activity` and tap the same `image` again.

Picasso

```
Picasso.with(
     context)
     .load('url')
     .into(mImage);
```

It is also worth mentioning that it has no problem loading the full image (frame) of a video file that is part of my album collection. That one I tap on it and it loads the `image` no problem. I don't know why.

Now, I did some research and looked around a few forums where people seemed to be having my same problem and they recommend Glide. Promptly I set it up in my project and give it a try and my images work, I get full size images the first time I select a thumbnail.

Glide:

```
        Glide.with(context)
              .asBitmap()
              .load('url')
              .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(mImage) 
               {
                   @Override
                   public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) 
                   {
                       super.onResourceReady(resource, transition);
                                   mImage.setImageBitmap(resource);
                                   mImage.setZoom(1);
                   }
                });
```

My question is: why did Glide provided me with a better result than `picasso` did? What was I missing to make `Picasso` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , i guess nothing wrong with **Picasso** , i think it's just some delay caused by internet connection .

**Glide** and **Picasso** are technically the same , and you should use the last version of them next time

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

and also , since we are talking about images , you have to know that both **Picasso** and **Glide** have issues with loading some https url and for that i advice you to use **[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)**

Comment: thanks for the reply. I set up Universa Image Loader but now i am not getting any fill images at all. this is what I've done:

         ''ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        imageLoader.displayImage('url', mImage);''